# Installing Linux on a Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot

I would like to clean install a Linux distribution as Ubuntu etc. My laptop runs Windows 8.1.

I have two options in mind. Clean install or dual boot.

My technical question is: My laptop have a 8GB SSD drive, which it uses to boot Windows with and a 500GB for storage. I wonder what that 8GB SSD stores? It can't store the whole Windows install as that would be much more than 8GB. Also if I would do a clean install of Ubuntu could I use the 8GB SSD to have Ubuntu boot up quicker. How would I install it? Option two, if I would like to dual boot, how would I proceed having the SSD to boot both systems?

I also wish to ask about the Legacy and UEFI differences. Windows runs with UEFI. So when I'm installing Linux, should I run Legacy, and if I dual boot, what option to I choose?

Answer (score -1):

You could install a virtual machine software onto your Windows 8 (such as VirtualBox) and you can then install Ubuntu onto this, get it communicating with your hardware (Internet, USBs, audio, CD/DVD writer etc.) and use it simultaneously with Windows 8... virtual machines are excellent nowadays and are often much easier to set up than dual booting the normal way... Yes, they use your computer hardware resources (processor, RAM, hard disk space) but machines nowadays are fast enough and have enough resources to do much of what the average user demands.

Comment: This is not an option for two reasons. First is that my laptops hardware requirements are not high enough to run a VM. Second is that I prefer Linux as main system as I use it to work with.

Comment: Also, an 8GB SSD... is this a whole disk on its own? Or is the disk a hybrid SSD where 8GB is SSD and the rest is mechanical? I'm also unsure how you managed to install Windows 8 onto your SSD when Windows 8 requires 16GB of storage space - according to the Microsoft site.

Comment: If you are sure you want to dual-boot to, say,  Ubuntu, then you need to download the EFI version that should let you dual-boot. It will install GRUB to give you the option to choose which OS to boot to. Did your laptop come with the SSD and installed with Windows 8? I'm just wondering, as most new computers that have such devices as SSDs do have virtualization capability... Have you checked your BIOS?

Comment: Not sure of the downvote when the answer I gave was perfectly acceptable as a possible solution for the OP. VirtualBox can run a 32-Bit guest OS without VT-X on the BIOS. The original question didn't specifically state the OP couldn't use a VM...

Comment: superuser.com has allot of down votes on posts for no reasons. Your answer though didn't relate to my question, as I didn't ask for an possible solution. So I can understand the down vote in this particular matter, for who ever voted.